# Deterministic Finite Automata Regular Expression with na(w) and nb(w) over a language

Tags: regex, regular-language, automata, dfa

I'm trying to find the regular expression for the following language on {a,b}

L = {w:(na(w) + nb(w)) mod 3 < 2 }

I would like to split this up into:

L1 = {w: (na(w) + nb(w)) mod 3 = 0 }

L2 = {w: (na(w) + nb(w)) mod 3 = 1 }

and then use L1 Union L2 to solve.

I think I've solved na(w) mod 3 = 0 by using
( b* ab* ab* ab* )*

However, I'm not sure how to handle na(w) + na(b) and the 2 conditions for mod 3 < 2 in one single regular expression

Answer (score 1):

Assuming na(w) represents how many as appear in w, the fact that your alphabet is {a, b} means that na(w) + nb(w) is the length of w.

So the problem is to accept the language of strings over {a,b} with length 3k or 3k+1. A regular expression for this language is

```
((a|b)(a|b)(a|b))*(a|b|empty)
```